# __try __except not working in "Array bounds exceed" state

Tags: c, error-handling, try-except

I have to use `__try` and `__except` statements to handle possible memory `errors` as bellow :

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>


INT main()
{
    CHAR a[5] = { 0 };
    // literal string
    CHAR *b = "hello12345";

    __try
    {
        StrCpyA(a, b);
    }
    __except ((GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_ARRAY_BOUNDS_EXCEEDED) ? EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER : EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH)
    {
        printf("Array bounds exceeded!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

While running, the program stops with an error unexpectedly when using of `__try` and `__except` And no exception occurred in `__except()` block!

By the way, I'm using of windows API `typedef's`

Any Suggestion?

Comment: undefined behavior is undefined

Comment: @Stargateur sorry, i didnt get you?

Comment: @Stargateur please help me...

Comment: There is nothing to add, you expect precise behavior for something that has undefined behavior. Exception are not magic, don't trust window API, this isn't something you can do in C. Change to C# for feature like this, There is no point to use C, if you want automatic bound checking.